# Text file comparison using Spark data frames

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to implement below requirement using Spark dataframes to compare 2 text/csv

- List item

files. Ideally, File1.txt should compare with File2.txt and result should be in other txt file with flag as (SAME/UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE).

UPDATE - if any record values are updated in file2 when compared to file1
INSERT - if a new record exist in file2
DELETE - only if the record exist in file1 (not in file2)
SAME - if same record exist in both files

```
File1.txt
NO  DEPT NAME   SAL 
1   IT  RAM     1000    
2   IT  SRI     600 
3   HR  GOPI    1500    
5   HW  MAHI    700 

File2.txt
NO  DEPT NAME   SAL 
1   IT   RAM    1000    
2   IT   SRI    900 
4   MT   SUMP   1200    
5   HW   MAHI   700

Outputfile.txt
NO  DEPT NAME    SAL   FLAG
1   IT  RAM     1000    S
2   IT  SRI     900     U
4   MT  SUMP    1200    I
5   HW  MAHI    700     S
3   HR  GOPI    1500    D
```

So far, i did below coding. But not able to proceed further. Pls help.

```
from pyspark.shell import spark
sc = spark.sparkContext
df1 = spark.read.option("header","true").option("delimiter", ",").csv("C:\\inputs\\file1.csv")
df2 = spark.read.option("header","true").option("delimiter", ",").csv("C:\\inputs\\file2.csv")

df1.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("table2")

sqlDF1 = spark.sql( "select * from table1" )
sqlDF2 = spark.sql( "select * from table2" )

leftJoinDF = sqlDF1.join(sqlDF2, 'id', how='left')
rightJoinDF = sqlDF1.join(sqlDF2, 'id', how='right')
innerJoinDF = sqlDF1.join(sqlDF2, 'id')
```

Is there any way if we merge the data, after performing leftJoin, rightJoin, innerJoin. With this whether i could get desired output or any other way.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find my solution below. I create 4 dataframe for SAME/UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE cases and then union them

```py
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
>>> import pyspark.sql.functions as F

>>> df1 = sc.parallelize([
...     (1,'IT','RAM',1000),    
...     (2,'IT','SRI',600),
...     (3,'HR','GOPI',1500),    
...     (5,'HW','MAHI',700)
...     ]).toDF(['NO','DEPT','NAME','SAL'])
>>> df1.show()
+---+----+----+----+
| NO|DEPT|NAME| SAL|
+---+----+----+----+
|  1|  IT| RAM|1000|
|  2|  IT| SRI| 600|
|  3|  HR|GOPI|1500|
|  5|  HW|MAHI| 700|
+---+----+----+----+

>>> df2 = sc.parallelize([
...     (1,'IT','RAM',1000),    
...     (2,'IT','SRI',900),
...     (4,'MT','SUMP',1200),    
...     (5,'HW','MAHI',700)
...     ]).toDF(['NO','DEPT','NAME','SAL'])
>>> df2.show()
+---+----+----+----+
| NO|DEPT|NAME| SAL|
+---+----+----+----+
|  1|  IT| RAM|1000|
|  2|  IT| SRI| 900|
|  4|  MT|SUMP|1200|
|  5|  HW|MAHI| 700|
+---+----+----+----+

#DELETE
>>> df_d = df1.join(df2, df1.NO == df2.NO, 'left').filter(F.isnull(df2.NO)).select(df1.NO,df1.DEPT,df1.NAME,df1.SAL, F.lit('D').alias('FLAG'))
#INSERT
>>> df_i = df1.join(df2, df1.NO == df2.NO, 'right').filter(F.isnull(df1.NO)).select(df2.NO,df2.DEPT,df2.NAME,df2.SAL, F.lit('I').alias('FLAG'))
#SAME/
>>> df_s = df1.join(df2, df1.NO == df2.NO, 'inner').filter(F.concat(df2.NO,df2.DEPT,df2.NAME,df2.SAL) == F.concat(df1.NO,df1.DEPT,df1.NAME,df1.SAL)).\
...     select(df1.NO,df1.DEPT,df1.NAME,df1.SAL, F.lit('S').alias('FLAG'))
#UPDATE
>>> df_u = df1.join(df2, df1.NO == df2.NO, 'inner').filter(F.concat(df2.NO,df2.DEPT,df2.NAME,df2.SAL) != F.concat(df1.NO,df1.DEPT,df1.NAME,df1.SAL)).\
...     select(df2.NO,df2.DEPT,df2.NAME,df2.SAL, F.lit('U').alias('FLAG'))


>>> dfs = [df_s,df_u,df_u,df_i]
>>> df = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, dfs)
>>> 
>>> df.show()
+---+----+----+----+----+                                                       
| NO|DEPT|NAME| SAL|FLAG|
+---+----+----+----+----+
|  5|  HW|MAHI| 700|   S|
|  1|  IT| RAM|1000|   S|
|  2|  IT| SRI| 900|   U|
|  2|  IT| SRI| 900|   U|
|  4|  MT|SUMP|1200|   I|
+---+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but in the above final result 2 clarifications i want to confirm :
1. The record (NO : 2) , repeating twice. Data is correct only.

Comment: sorry, i used df_u twice. you should change second df_u with df_d. It should be dfs = [df_s,df_u,df_d,df_i]. I used spark 2.3.0 too

Comment: try this -- df = df_d.union(df_i).union(df_s).union(df_u)

Comment: during concat in df_s and df_u, if there are any null values in (no, dept, name, sal) that record is not coming in the final output. is there any way to filter null values and to include them under suitable flag.

Comment: I tried by adding a null condition like below : (df2.NO!='null', df2.DEPT!='null', df2.NAME!='null' ,df2.SAL!='null') , but still the issue is coming.

Comment: try this for null value. from pyspark.sql.functions as F   F.isnull(df2['NO'])==False

Comment: Not able to use it properly, could you please elaborate the condition please ?

Comment: df1 :  9  IT       650                (3rd field is null)
df2 :  9  IT  TOM  750                                                                                                       When comparing the above record, it should come under U flag. Could you pls help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'outer'` join after concatenating all columns first. Then create an `udf` for flags.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = sql.createDataFrame([
     (1,'IT','RAM',1000),
     (2,'IT','SRI',600),
     (3,'HR','GOPI',1500),
     (5,'HW','MAHI',700)],
     ['NO'  ,'DEPT', 'NAME',   'SAL' ])

df1 = sql.createDataFrame([
     (1,'IT','RAM',1000),
     (2,'IT','SRI',900),
     (4,'MT','SUMP',1200 ),
     (5,'HW','MAHI',700)],
     ['NO'  ,'DEPT', 'NAME',   'SAL' ])

def flags(x,y):
    if not x:
        return y+'-I'
    if not y:
        return x+'-D'
    if x == y:
        return x+'-S'
    return y+'-U'

_cols = df.columns
flag_udf = F.udf(lambda x,y: flags(x,y),StringType())   


df = df.select(['NO']+ [F.concat_ws('-', *[F.col(_c) for _c in df.columns]).alias('f1')])\
        .join(df1.select(['NO']+ [F.concat_ws('-', *[F.col(_c1) for _c1 in df1.columns]).alias('f2')]), 'NO', 'outer')\
        .select(flag_udf('f1','f2').alias('combined'))
df.show()
```

The result will be,

```py
+----------------+                                                              
|        combined|
+----------------+
| 5-HW-MAHI-700-S|
| 1-IT-RAM-1000-S|
|3-HR-GOPI-1500-D|
|  2-IT-SRI-900-U|
|4-MT-SUMP-1200-I|
+----------------+
```

Finally, split the `combined` column.

```py
split_col = F.split(df['combined'], '-')
df = df.select([split_col.getItem(i).alias(s) for i,s in enumerate(_cols+['FLAG'])])

df.show()
```

You get the desired output,

```py
+---+----+----+----+----+                                                       
| NO|DEPT|NAME| SAL|FLAG|
+---+----+----+----+----+
|  5|  HW|MAHI| 700|   S|
|  1|  IT| RAM|1000|   S|
|  3|  HR|GOPI|1500|   D|
|  2|  IT| SRI| 900|   U|
|  4|  MT|SUMP|1200|   I|
+---+----+----+----+----+
```